# jQuery overwrite data var in Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, arraylist

I try to use a Data Variable like this...  `$this.data()`.
 
But I have a problem to overwrite an Item.

I wanna use it to get some control and state information about the plugin.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(options) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var set = $.extend(true, {}, $.fn.meSlideMenu.defaults, options);

        $this.data({
            'menu': {
                'expand': false,
                'initDone': false,
                'runFirtTime': true
            },
            'item': {
                'clicked': false,
                'lastItem': 'Nothing'
            },
            'button': {
                'isVisible': false,
                'clicked': false
            }
        });

        /* some more stuff */

        $this.data('button').isVisible = true; /* both doesn't work */
        $this.data().button.isVisible = true;

        /* some stuff again */

        $.fn.myPlugin.defaults = {
            'debug': false,
            'name': 'meSlideMenu',
            'speed': 195,
        };
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: If you're trying to update the value in the object held in `data`, you'll need to amend the property's value in the object, then call the setter of `data()` again to update it.

Comment: Small side note.  I believe in this case `var $this = $(this);` is unnecessary.  Within the `$.fn` namespace, 'this' will already be a jQuery object.

Comment: ok, that sounds well, but my javascript skills are not that mature yet. Maybe do you have an example for me?

Comment: This approach seems to work correctly.  https://jsfiddle.net/ctd3rn9g/  Are you sure the value is not being updated?

Comment: yes, you're right...  it works.

Answer (score 0):

But it' better to use

```
window.console.debug( $this.data('menu') )
```

instead of

```
window.console.debug( $this.data() )
```